# Change lookup call of field

Tags: eclipse-scout

I have EntityField and UsersField(ListBox). When I change Entity to USERS, I need to pass: UsersLookupCall, when I change Entity to Projects, i need to pass ProjectUsersLookupCall to UsersField.

Also if that is possible, how to pass a parameter to that lookup call I am passing to another field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exchange the lookup-call on a (Smart-)Field simply by calling the `setLookupCall(ILookupCall<T>)` method on the field. However, since the value of the field is strongly typed and the type of the lookup must match the type of the field you can only set lookup calls with the same type.

You find a lot of examples on how to react on value changes in the [Scout Beginners Guide](https://eclipsescout.github.io/9.0/beginners-guide.html).

You can set additional parameters on the lookup call by implementing the `execPrepareLookup(ILookupCall<T>)` method. Note: there are also specialized execPrepare* methods for the three lookup modes: key, text and rec.